# Why my load balancer doesn't redirect to avaliable ec2 when cpu is 100%?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, amazon-ecs

I run my nodejs application in aws ecs.

I create in ecs a cluster. the cluster is running a service which run a task. 
Inside the task I have nginx (portMapping: 0:80 - dynamic port for ALB) and nodejs images.

The Dockerfiles are simple (nothing special there):

dockerfile nginx:

```
FROM nginx:latest

WORKDIR /

RUN echo "deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list

RUN apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get -y install apt-utils && \
    apt-get -y upgrade && \
    apt-get -y install nano && \
    apt-get -y clean

COPY ./nginx/nginx.conf  /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Dockerfile nodejs application:

```
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./package.json .

COPY ./app-prod-www.js .

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

and nginx.conf:

```
user  nginx;                                                                    

worker_processes 4;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;                                       
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;                                                  

http {                                                                          
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;                                        
    default_type  application/octet-stream;                                     

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '   
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '               
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';             

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;                                

    sendfile        on;                                                         
    #tcp_nopush     on;                                                         

    keepalive_timeout  65;                                                      

    #gzip  on;                                                                  

    # include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;                                           
    # include /etc/nginx/sites-available/*.conf;                                           

    upstream prodwww {   
        least_conn;                                                                                  
        server prod-www:3000 weight=10 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
    }

    server {                                                                                                  
        listen       80;                                                                                      

        location / {                                                                                         
            proxy_pass http://prodwww;                                                                     
            proxy_http_version 1.1;                                                                          
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;                                                          
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';                                                           
            proxy_set_header Host $host;                                                                     
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;                                                                
        }                                                                                                      
    }                                                                                                         
}
```

The cluster have two ec2 instances.

The service is running 4 tasks.

I set a ALB which should redirect the traffic to those ec2 instances.

But when I have 100% cpu in one of the containers then the ALB doesn't redirect the traffic to free ec2 machine.

I write a Fibonacci code when I access to the /test route. this will cause 100% cpu. and the nodejs application can't get any requests until it's complete (and Fibonacci(100) will take long time).

So after I access to `/test` route, I can see this take a lot to complete. meanwhile I open new tab in the browser and try to access the root route (`/`) which should serve the text `App Prod WWW`.

But I can see that it not responding. which mean the ALB still redirect me to this nodejs application instance.

Why is that? If I miss information here please let me know and I'll update my question.

Here my application:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

console.log('app prod www nodejs started');

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send(`App Prod WWW! ${process.pid}/${process.env.NAME}`));

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
  console.log('in test');
  function fibonacci(n) {
    return n < 1 ? 0 : n <= 2 ? 1 : fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
  }

  const x = fibonacci(100);
  console.log('after x');
  res.json({ x });
});

app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
  console.log('in api');
  res.json({ ok: true });
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default a load balancer will just use a round-robin algorithm to distribute requests evenly across all targets. The load balancer will periodically perform the health check that you have configured to ensure a target can accept requests.

The load balancer does not monitor the CPU usage of the targets. Until the periodic health checks for a target instance fails, the target will continue receiving requests.

Comment: Well, I don't know when my server will be busy. I need to set the ALB to check every 10 seconds for getting 200 from `/`?

Comment: I don't know enough about your application to tell you what that should be. Is one of your nodes really going to be utilizing 100% CPU when the other is not being utilized?

Comment: can be. basically I hope not, I write the code to be async all the time. but what if the cpu is 100%? I think about create a route `/health-check` just return json: `ok: true`. and in aws set health to this route. what you think about this idea?

Comment: What are the values for recommend about health check? Healthy threshold, unhealthy threshold, timeout, interval?

Comment: You should look into adding auto-scaling to increase the number of instances so that the average CPU usage across all instances stays below a certain threshold. I don't get your question about "what if the cpu is 100%"? Your question could be asked about any software ever written. My question is if the load is balanced across all your servers why is one going to be 100% when the others aren't?